# Getting Gradle error when starting STS

Tags: eclipse, gradle, spring-tool-suite

I am using STS 3.6.0 and during STS startup I am getting error:

```
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxConfiguration$1
Could not fetch model of type 'EclipseProject' using Gradle installation 'C:\build-tools\gradle-1.10'.
```

And I can't run Gradle task for the project. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message looks similar to the error in this bug [1].

This bug is actually caused by a bug in Eclipse 4.4.2 [2]. There are a few things you can do to avoid this bug:

- You can try a more recent version of gradle tooling (and/or STS)
- install the workaround from eclipse update site as explained in comment 51 [3] of the Eclipse bug

[1] https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3922

[2] https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=445122

[3] https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=445122#c51